# Flink: purging windows metadata when using allowed lateness

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How can I 'get rid' of window metadata (WindowOperator and InternalTimer) before the allowed lateness period is over?

Is it possible to purge this metadata along with the window data itself?

We don't mind losing the metadata - late events with same key+time are not require to be handled based on context of previous non-late data.

Some background -

[Currently using Flink-v1.6] 
We are working with event-time windowing and dealing with a huge number of events having a unique key. 95% of the events do not arrive late and will only fire once.

Our job is set to allow lateness of 72 hours. We use fire & purge, but still the allowed lateness mechanism results a huge state (keeping all those windows metadata) which we want to reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you need custom state management, I recommend using a ProcessFunction instead of Flink's window API, as it's much easier to understand and maintain than having related logic possibly spread across a window assigner, trigger, evictor, and process window function.

In your case one idea does come to mind: would it work for you if instead of having a long period of allowed lateness, you collected the late events to a side output?

Update:

The metadata that is retained is the state that is needed to be able to continue adding events to the window. This is the price one pays for allowing late events.

Comment: Thank you David for the response.

Comment: Can you please describe why does Flink keeps 'pane' metadata for windowSize + allowedLateness? Can I configure that this metadata will not be kept at all in memory?

Comment: Indeed, the ProcessFunction would give a the amount freedom we need (at least from a naive perspective - it's being checked at the moment). 
Comparing the ProcessFunction to window API, is there any metadata saved which might bring us back to the same memory issue?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd proposal, it would work under certain ordering conditions of our raw data. The problem is that once in a while we might encounter an end case scenario in which a huge amount of 'late' data will be inserted. If we use window API with this side output it would bring us back to square one. 
Did you mean we could process the side output stream in a different manner?

Comment: A ProcessFunction does not have any implicit (hidden) state. Only the state that you explicitly instantiate -- including any Timers you might create.

Comment: In the side output for late events scenario, the window and its trigger would be purged when the window ends, clearing all of its state. Late events would then be processed in whatever way you establish, independently of the original window that they failed to be included in.

Comment: If the concern is fitting everything into memory, you do have the option of using the RocksDB state backend for keyed state (including keyed window state) and timers. This will move the state to local disk, with an in-memory (off-heap) cache.

Comment: Thanks, David.  
Again, i'm interested in why metadata like WindowOperator and InternalTimer are being kept for windowSize + allowedLateness period per each pane.

What is the purpose of keeping this data if no new events are expected to enter the pane?

Is there any way this metadata can be released earlier?